# Relationship between Membership.UserIsOnlineTimeWindow and FormsAuthentication.Timeout Random Logouts

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

As late, I've started noticing that my web application randomly logs out a user after a random amount of requests between pages. I've gone through all possible scenarios and have noticed that it only happens when the `UserIsOnlineTimeWindow` property (of the `Membership` provider) doesn't equal the default `FormsAuthentication` `Timeout` property.

Does the `UserIsOnlineTimeWindow` affect the default `FormAuthentication` provider?

Do they need to be the same?

If so, please explain ...

The following is pretty self-explanatory, though it doesn't describe any relation between the default `Membership` API and `FormsAuthentication` *(with regards to the aforementioned properties affecting one another)*:

> Specifies the number of minutes after the last-activity date/time stamp for a user during which the user is considered online.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.userisonlinetimewindow

Comment: If it can be easily reproduce, I recommend you spend some time learning Fiddler, http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/, then you can use it to track all HTTP requests/responses so as to better understand what happens on the wire. It does not only reveal you more details, but demonstrate clearly how forms authentication is implemented as well.

Answer (score 1):

that does seem strange.  UserIsOnLine Time does not update anything I know of.  I'd suggest looking at the cookie in a browser like chrome with the dev tools and actually check what the expire time on the cookie is. Best I know, that is the only thing that will cause a logout (besides deleting the cookie)